How would heavier neutrinos result in a more rapid expansion of the universe and less clumpiness of other matter? Rather than the opposite?
I've read that the heavier neutrinos (allegedly) are, the MORE rapid the expansion of the Universe would have been and the LESS clumsy other, regular matter would be....
Shouldn't the opposite be true?  Heavier neutrinos slow down the expansion of the universe and result in denser, clumpier galactic clusters?

"I've read...". Please give example sources.
